# Auto capitalize letters in bounded forms

Tags: ms-access, vba

i have a bounded, continuous form with some textbox that users can modify.
I want to use some code to auto capitalize what ever the users typed, like

```
Private Sub textbox_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.textbox = UCase(Me.textbox)
End Sub
```

but it causes error... Any suggestions?

And I noticed that in a bounded, continuous form, I can't move the pointer in its recordset.

```
Me.Recordset.MoveNext
```

This causes error (number 3462). Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the UCase expression in the text box control's After Update event.

```
Private Sub textbox_AfterUpdate()
    Me.textbox = UCase(Me.textbox)
End Sub
```

As for the second question, this works without error for a command button on my form.

```
Private Sub cmdMoveNext_Click()
    Me.Recordset.MoveNext
End Sub
```

This is what I get in the Immediate Window for your error number.

```
? AccessError(3462)
Failure to load a DLL.
```

Is that the error text you see?  If so, I don't know the cause, but I would wonder if your database is corrupt.  Can you re-create a simplified version of this form in a new database to see whether it works there?  If it also fails then, perhaps your Access installation is broken.

Frankly, I'm just grasping at straws.  This seems very unusual to me.

Comment: Thanks! What's the difference between before and after update?

Comment: Before update on a data control is when you check whether the value is valid ... assign True to Cancel when invalid ... to prevent the user from moving to another control before she fixes the invalid problem.  After update happens once the changed control value has been accepted and the user is moving on to another control.

Comment: Before and After update on the form are different.  Those happen immediately before and after the form's bound values are **stored** to the row source.

Comment: ah...Because it's a bounded forms, so i thought it's BeforeUpdate(to the database) and AfterUpdate(to the database)...

Comment: Right!  Another way to look at it is to check Me.Dirty after updating a bound data control.  You'll see what I mean.  :-)

Comment: Have a look at the help file for the events of controls versus the events of forms. The explanations there will clarify the differences that are presently puzzling you.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question:
Use the Keypress event to check for lower case letter and then return it's upper case counter-part:

```
Private Sub textbox_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
  Const ASCII_LOWER_A = 97
  Const ASCII_LOWER_Z = 122
  Const UPPER_MODIFIER = -32

  If KeyAscii >= ASCII_LOWER_A And KeyAscii <= ASCII_LOWER_Z Then
    KeyAscii = KeyAscii + UPPER_MODIFIER
  End If

End Sub
```

---

**UPDATE**:  Since I received criticism and a downvote for my answer, I will elaborate on when and why you might use the code above.

First, let me say that the *After_Update* event fires after the control tied to that event loses focus (either via tab or actually moving to the next record).  *After_Update*  also recognizes a paste if the user cuts and pastes text; admittedly, my code does not.  If your only concern is storing the text in the database in upper case, by all means use *After_Update* to UCase the value.

However, there is one advantage that *KEY_PRESS* press will give you: the ability to correct the letter pressed in real time.

To the purist developer, this event may seem wasteful.  However, anyone who’s received a paycheck from a company should recognize that keeping their paying client happy is imperative.  If that paid client says “*I want to see capital letters when the user starts typing*”, then you would use the code above.  It will have little (if any) impact on how the application behaves and will meet your boss's requirement.

In fact, maybe the client says “*Hey, this field is for putting in serial numbers for our inventory.  All of  products’ serial numbers use zeros, not the letter O.  So please make sure they do not enter O for this field*.”

Now *KEY_PRESS* has an additional use.  You could either negate the letter O being pressed or you can replace the letter O getting pressed by the value you need:

```
Private Sub TextBox_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    Const ASCII_LOWER_A = 97
    Const ASCII_LOWER_Z = 122
    Const UPPER_MODIFIER = -32

    Const UPPER_O = 79
    Const LOWER_O = 111
    Const ZERO_ASCII = 48

    Select Case KeyAscii

        Case UPPER_O, LOWER_O
            KeyAscii = 0 'Cancel it out
            'KeyAscii = ZERO_ASCII 'OR Replace it with the number zero
        Case ASCII_LOWER_A To ASCII_LOWER_Z
            KeyAscii = KeyAscii + UPPER_MODIFIER  'The old familiar code that will capitalize all other letters
        Case Else
        'Whatever other validations you want to do on the textbox here.

    End Select

End Sub
```

So what about cutting and pasting invalid values?  That is what Form_BeforeUpdate event is for.  You can check all values before you save and set Cancel  = True if something doesn’t jive.

It’s a very useful event and completly applicable if you want to UCase letters in real time.

Comment: This fires for every keystroke. You want an event that fires only once, and that's AfterUpdate.

Comment: Why did you suggest `KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger`?  That requires setting a non-standard reference to avoid a compile error: "User-defined type not defined".  If you want to go this route, seems like `KeyAscii As Integer` would be preferable.

Comment: If the user pastes text into the text box, it will not get converted to upper case with this method. Also, if the bound field contains text already, none of that will be converted to upper case, although any characters added through the control will be.  Neither of those may be deal-killers, but after update gives you an easy way to assure that all the characters in the updated field get converted to upper case.

Comment: @HansUp For you first point, my mistake.  I had code from Excel I cut and paste from there; corrected.  For values that already exist, it shouldn't be an issue if you make the form the only way to manipulate the data.  For pasting...well, there's a few ways to go...one of them being using "AFTER_UPDATE" :P...but still the question asks to autocapitalize when the user types...so, may not be applicable.

Comment: I was thinking about data added to the table by other means, like an import.  It seems unlikely to me someone would want only the newly-added characters, for values added/updated through the form, upper-cased.  And you're also right that we have no idea whether those issues apply in this situation ... that's why I wrote maybe not deal-killers.  After working with your code, I decided I like it better than I did at first. If a client is adamant she must see the characters upper-cased immediately, I will use it.  Probably do UCase in after update, too.  :-)  +1 from me.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried putting it in the `TextBox1_Change` Sub ???

Comment: Yes i have copied these in the change event but nothing happen. This event isn't even triggered.

Comment: Change fires for every keystroke, so would be a terrible choice.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton Please read @Ray023 comment below. you've downvoted both his and my answers, agian are you concerned about processing power. Also I could accpet the downvote if you had offered a better alternative. Yes the change event fires for every keystroke, but the processing power is really nothing these days as the machine won't being doing much except waiting for keystrokes.

Comment: I'm not at all concerned about processing power -- you just made that up. I'm concerned about answers that suggest the WRONG event to be used when there's one whose purpose is specific to the kind of operation involved in the question asked. While this answer would work, it's not by any means the BEST answer -- hence the downvote, so that the BEST answer has the highest rating. Isn't that the way this stuff is supposed to work?

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
Private Sub textbox_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim strBuffer As String
    strBuffer = Me.textbox
    Me.textbox.Focus
    Me.textbox = UCase(strBuffer)
End Sub
```

Comment: Updating in the BeforeUpdate causes a recursion problem, so you shouldn't ever do anything there other than Undo (with Cancel=True).